# How to connect Hive/Presto via JDBC to Amazon QuickSight (SPICE)

Tags: amazon-web-services, jdbc, hive, presto, amazon-quicksight

I would like to connect a Hive/Preso query engine within AWS to Amazon QuickSight (SPICE) to query the data. Usually I would use JDBC (https://prestodb.io/docs/current/installation/jdbc.html) for this.

Is this already possible? Or is there another way to do set up this connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not possible currently with QuickSight.  See: https://quicksight.aws/

From the link:

"Choose your data source
You can upload CSV or Excel files; ingest data from AWS data sources such as Amazon Redshift, Amazon RDS, Amazon Aurora, Amazon Athena, and Amazon S3; connect to databases like SQL Server, MySQL, and PostgreSQL, in the cloud or on-premises; or connect to SaaS applications like Salesforce. Future releases will let you ingest data from Amazon EMR, Amazon DynamoDB, and Amazon Kinesis as well as other cloud applications."